# Converting File into Desired Output

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

Input: file with several lines of strings, each line is a separate string:

```
1234,123,345 
4567,56,76 
1029,192,13
```

Output: list of lists, where each line is a separate list

```
[[1234,123,345],[4567,56,76],[1029,192,13]]
```

Usually I have been able to do these because the input did not have commas and were just spaced out, but each line is one string, so it is throwing me off.

So far, I have:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    info = f.readlines()
solution = []
for line in info:
    solution.append([line])
print solution
```

But this yields:

```
[['1234,123,345\n'],['4567,56,76\n'],['1029,192,13\n']]
```

I have an idea for a fix where I do another for loop, get each character, and append each non-comma to another array and then convert to int. But this sounds complex and the newline tag was confusing me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an idea for a fix where I do another for loop, get each character, and append each non-comma to another array and then convert to int. But this sounds complex…

You're right—that *would* work, but it's not the easiest way to do it.

Just use the `split` method on strings, like this:

```
for line in info:
    solution.append(line.split(","))
```

Now, instead of each line being `['1234,123,345\n']`, it will be `['1234', '123', '345\n']`.

This gets you close, but those are still strings, not ints. An inner loop to convert each one to an int, just as you suggested, will work great. But it might be easier to read with a for loop in a list comprehension, rather than in a for statement. Like this:

```
for line in info:
    solution.append([int(number) for number in line.split(",")])
```

If you don't understand the comprehension, here it is as a statement:

```
for line in info:
    numbers = []
    for number in line.split(","):
        numbers.append(int(number))
    solution.append(numbers)
```

And, since the `int` function can ignore whitespace, `int('345\n')` is `345`, so you don't have to do anything else.

But if you *did* have to do something else, `rstrip` would be the easiest answer: it removes all whitespace from the end of a string. So:

```
for line in info:
    solution.append([int(number) for number in line.rstrip().split(",")])
```

Comment: @NoobCoder list comprehension will create a list and the returned list can be directly assigned to `numbers`

Comment: @NoobCoder: Yes, a list comprehension like `numbers = [int(foo) for foo in bar]` is exactly the same thing as `numbers = []` followed by `for foo in bar: numbers.append(int(foo))` (except shorter, and faster to run). (You may notice that you could also replace the _outer_ loop with a list comprehension, nesting one inside the other. But that can get hard to read—there's a delicate balance between not being compact enough vs. being too cryptic.)

Comment: Outside of looking very nice, is there any advantage to list comprehension- is it any faster than normal list/for loops?

Comment: Input data is separated with commas, not with spaces :)

Comment: ah you just forgot the "," in each .split(). now it works. thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: @NoobCoder just change `split()` to `split(",")`.

Comment: @NoobCoder: It is generally faster than a loop—although that usually doesn't make a difference. Also, it prevents you from leaking the `foo` variable into the outer scope, which is sometimes helpful in organizing complex code. But most of the time, whichever one is more readable is better.

Comment: @NoobCoder: By the way, if you want to know exactly how and why it's faster (in a specific implementation, like CPython 3.4), it might be an interesting thing to learn… depending on what you find interesting. And I could point you to the right places to get started. But otherwise, "it's faster, but usually not enough to matter" is probably enough, and if it ever isn't enough, use `timeit` to test exactly how much faster for your actual code/data/platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the new line character, with [`rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) and then [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string based on `,`. Next you can convert the strings to numbers with [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    print [map(int, line.rstrip().split(",")) for line in f]
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer, very succinct- would have accepted but other poster wrote a lot and explained in depth